# How to get users to show up on firebase backend?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I would like to authenticate my flutter app using google sign in with a firebase backend. I have started the app in firebase and added the necessary config file. My login logic is as follows.

```
Future<String> signInWithGoogle() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
      await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );

  final FirebaseUser user =
      (await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential));

  assert(!user.isAnonymous);
  assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

  final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
  assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

  return 'signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user';
}

void signOutGoogle() async {
  await googleSignIn.signOut();

  print("User Sign Out");
}
```

Surrounding this code is the UI to display the button but this is the code that integrates with Firebase. However, when I use it to sign in it sends me to a google sign-in page but firebase does not reflect any new users. Why is this the case?

Comment: Is your `signInWithCredential` call being executed, and is it successful? Also: where are you checking for the new user to show up?

Comment: I was checking on the firebase console. I believe the I needed to complete the setup on firebase more completely but a coworkers PR recently solved the issue

Comment: Good to hear Josh. In that case I'm voting to close the issue as "not reproducible".

Comment: No problem. Is there any action I need to take?